# Qt blockSignals is not blocking first extra click

Tags: c++, qt, events, queue

I am trying to have extra clicks on a QPushButton do nothing by using QObject's blockSignals method within a slot function connected to the button. Then, I am firing a queued connection signal that is connected to a slot which unblocks the button's signals.

My idea here is that blocking operations like a database operation, represented by the sleep call in the code below, might induce the user into extra-clicking the button. My approach to resolve this is to block the button's signals after the first click so that the extra-clicks accumulated during the blocking operation would do nothing, the spontaneous event queue would become completed, and then the posted event queue would process the queued signal which would unblock the button and return the application to its normal state.

My issue is that the first click processes, but the first extra click, which should be blocked, unexpectedly processes. Subsequent extra clicks do nothing.

Here is the code:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QPushButton *btn;

signals:
    void delayed_unblock();

private slots:
    void doStuff();
    void unblock();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

... and the rest of the code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTest>

int num = 0;

void MainWindow::doStuff() {

    qDebug() << btn->signalsBlocked();
    qDebug() << btn;
    qDebug() << sender();
    qDebug() << num++;
    btn->blockSignals(true);
    QTest::qSleep(5000);
    emit(delayed_unblock());
}

void MainWindow::unblock() {

    btn->blockSignals(false);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
      btn(new QPushButton("foo"))
{
    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::doStuff);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::delayed_unblock,
            this, &MainWindow::unblock,
            Qt::QueuedConnection);

    setCentralWidget(btn);
}
```

If I click the button 4 times rapidly, the debug console does this:

```
false
QPushButton(0x3e8840)
QPushButton(0x3e8840)
0
false
QPushButton(0x3e8840)
QPushButton(0x3e8840)
1
```

I was expecting the output to just be

```
false
QPushButton(0x3e8840)
QPushButton(0x3e8840)
0
```

because, to my understanding, the first click leads to a synchronous slot call which can block any ensuing button signals from occurring. The ensuing signals in my case are originating from mouse click events in the spontaneous event queue. Seemingly, all extra clicks should be blocked but that first extra click is still getting through.

If it is any help, clicking once, waiting 3 seconds, then clicking 3 times rapidly leads to the same results above.

My compiler is MSVC 2015.

Comment: Have you considered disabling and re-enabling the button? This will be more intuitive to the user.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I'm curious to find out what exactly is going on to lead to the unexpected results given my current setup. Of course, it's something I'm just not seeing.

Comment: Perhaps check that `signalsBlocked()` returns true during `doStuff()`? I can't think of any logical reason it would return false, but I lack other ideas. You could try [`QSignalBlocker`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html) for scoped signal blocking as an alternative to the queued unblock signal, as well.

Comment: Just edited question showing the `signalsBlocked()` results during `doStuff()`. As expected, it reaffirms that the `btn->blockSignals(true)` call in the first `doStuff()` doesn't seem to take since `signalsBlocked()` returns false in the second `doStuff()`.

Comment: Also, I was thinking maybe the `btn->blockSignals(true)` call could be asynchronous somehow, but clicking once, waiting 3 seconds, then clicking 3 times rapidly led to the same results.

Comment: Could you please print out the pointer values of `btn` and of `sender()` in `doStuff()`. As far as I can see from https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html#1420 and from https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html#3612 everything should work as intended. If not, for any reason, the identities are ambiguous.

Comment: Question updated to print out pointer values of `btn` and of `sender()` in `doStuff()`.

Comment: Well, put a debug message in `MainWindow::unblock()`. Maybe you're unblocking the signals in between.

Comment: That's actually after the first click the case.

Comment: Found out **why** and put a detailed explanation at the top of my answer. Thanks for this interesting question and your persistence to ask for the reason behind : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging into the dispatch mechanism of Qt shows what happens in which order. From this it becomes obvious why this strange behavior occurs.

From the backtrace I digged into g_main_context_dispatch of glib 2.0 used by Qt to dispatch events.

Within this function the events are dipatched in separate groups (queues). E.g. first all posted events, then all X11/Windows events, etc. if any.

Please note that a single mouse click, which consists of a press and release event results usually in two consectuive queues because they are processed so fast.

Means the "press" enters the queue, this queue, containing this SINGLE event ist processed more or less immediately and the "release" enters the next queue and is also processed immediately (always AFTER some posted events triggered by the program or so).

Only if the processing of something (like a qSleep(), takes longer, the queues may contain more than a single event per group.

I set three breakpoints and installed an eventfilter on mainwindow and the button. This way it was possible to see how everything interacts.

```
gdb$ info breakpoints

Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
2       breakpoint     keep y   0xb6d41db2 <g_main_context_dispatch+578>
        breakpoint already hit 549 times
        silent
        p "dispatch"
        continue

4       breakpoint     keep y   0xb6d41bdd <g_main_context_dispatch+109>
        breakpoint already hit 546 times
        silent
        p $ebp
        continue

5       breakpoint     keep y   0xb6d41bc9 <g_main_context_dispatch+89>
        breakpoint already hit 551 times
        silent
        p "leaving"
        continue
```

Note that I put "continue" in all break point commands. So the debugging did not block the app at any point.

The result for four consecutive clicks (three within the qSleep()) is as follows:

```
// Dispatch function entered, one queue with events available
$1528 = (void *) 0x1

// dispatching results in the pressEvent received by the button
$1529 = "dispatch"
"QPushButton(0x809d128) press" 

// dispatch function left, the spontaneous event queue
// contained only the mouse press
$1530 = "leaving"

// again entering with events in 2 queues, no idea what for
$1531 = (void *) 0x2

// dispatching of both doesn't result in press or release events
$1532 = "dispatch"


$1533 = "dispatch"


$1534 = "leaving"

// Huh, another leaving, obviously no events in any queue
$1535 = "leaving"

// Once more dispatching with nothing of interest for us
$1536 = (void *) 0x1


$1537 = "dispatch"


$1538 = "leaving"

// here comes the queue containing the release event
// of the first click
$1539 = (void *) 0x1

// the dispatch results in the release event and the button
// triggers the doStuff() function.
$1540 = "dispatch"
"QPushButton(0x809d128) release" 
false 
0

// -----
// Now the qSleep() runs for 5 secs. I clicked 3 times.
// There is no way Qt can process the individual presses
//and releases. The window system buffers them until Qt has time. 
// -----
// qSleep() finished, the signal for UNBLOCKING is emitted
// and the connected signal is enqueued in the posted events queue.
// -----

// leave the dispatching function
$1541 = "leaving"

// -----
// Now Qt receives the three remaining mouse clicks at once
// and puts ALL of them in a SINGLE spontaneous queue.

// enters the dispatching function, two queues contain events
$1542 = (void *) 0x2

// first queue dispatched, the one with the posted event
// unblocking occurs
$1543 = "dispatch"
"MainWindow(0xbfffe180) queued"
unblock() 

// second queue dispatched,
// the one with the THREE press/release pairs !!!
$1544 = "dispatch"

// first press/release pair triggers button clicked signal
// and that in turn the signal blocking
"QPushButton(0x809d128) press" 
"QPushButton(0x809d128) release" 
false 
1

// ----- 
// now the signals are blocked and qSleep() runs
// qSleep() finished and the signal for UNBLOCKING is emitted
// and the connected signal enqueued in the posted events queue. 
// follwing two press/release pairs don't trigger the
// clicked signal (due to the blocking)
// -----

"QPushButton(0x809d128) press"
"QPushButton(0x809d128) release"
"QPushButton(0x809d128) press"
"QPushButton(0x809d128) release" 

// leaving dispatch function
$1545 = "leaving"

// entering again the dispatch function with two queues
// containing events
$1546 = (void *) 0x2

// the unblocking
$1547 = "dispatch"
"MainWindow(0xbfffe180) queued" 
unblock() 

// and something unknown
$1548 = "dispatch"


$1549 = "leaving"
```

So it becomes obious **why** the posted unblocking interferes with the clicks. **No chance to block all the clicks because qt handles the posted events (the unblocking) before the others.** Only the en-bloc processing of the buffered clicks "seems" to work.

It's good to keep this in mind if blocking signals is used in conjunction with time consuming processing.

This also explains why my "hack" (see below) using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` to invoke the **SIGNAL** works. **It causes a redirection and needs two posted events.** First for the SIGNAL (which is otherwise called immediately with emit()) and second for the SLOT. Only then unblocking occurs. By then the additional clicks have been dispatched while the button was still silenced:

```
1. click // dispatched, blocking

qSleep() // meanwhile clicking 3 times
         // followed by enqueuing the SIGNAL
         // followed by enqueuing the 3 clicks in a single queue

unblocking SIGNAL // dispatched, unblocks not yet

2.,3., and 4. click // dispatched, but button still blocked

unblocking SLOT // dispatched, finally unblocks
```

In my "solution" below, with uses the **non-blocking local eventloop** instead of the blocking qSleep(), the **three clicks would have been processed immediately** (instead of after the unblock has been enqueued) and **no signal would have been emitted.**

---

**SOLUTION** while keeping qSleep():

I solved the problem by using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` to invoke the SIGNAL:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "delayed_unblock", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

instead of `emit(delayed_unblock());`

---

**SOLUTION** using a local event loop:

```
void MainWindow::doStuff()
{

qDebug() << btn->signalsBlocked();
qDebug() << num++;
btn->blockSignals(true);

QTimer t;
t.setSingleShot(true);
t.setInterval(5000);
QEventLoop loop;
connect(&t, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
t.start();
loop.exec(); // lets event processing happen nothing blocked (no mopuseclicks stuck in the windows system !?)

//QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "delayed_unblock", Qt::QueuedConnection);
emit(delayed_unblock());

}
```

---

**SOLUTION** using processEvents right after qSleep()

`QApplication::processEvents();` seems to receive and dispatch the windows system events immediately. This also solves the problem.

---

### Left following lines for historical reasons ; )

Because the doc of Qt 5.6 tells us that "Signals emitted while being blocked are not buffered." Thinking of it .. nothing is emitted at all because qSleep() blocks the app. completely. So it should be the case that Qt doesn't get a grip of the clicked mouse buttons at all (which is still stuck in Windows or X11) before the qSleep() finishes. And it should be due to the windows system that clicks are buffered. The first of that clicks is processed after everything else, including unblocking, after the timer finished. For the remaining clicks the signals are again blocked by then. (@thuga explains that well).

Comment: What happens if you don't unblock the signal at any point, do you still get two `MainWindow::doStuff()` calls? If not, then it seems that you unblock the signals before the 2nd click actually happens.

Comment: That is what happens. See above the `unblock()` debug output after the first click. So it's unblocked and the second click (which should not be there at all) is processed (which again blocks the signals [which works from that point on])

Comment: What makes you think the 2nd click shouldn't be there at all?

Comment: Thanks @thuga, that pointed me to what the reason and the solution should be. See the last part in my answer.

Comment: I think what the documentation is saying re: _"Signals emitted while being blocked are not buffered."_ is that it is not like `blockSignals(true)` puts the signals into a buffer which are then flushed when `blockSignals(false)` is called sometime later.

Comment: Actually Qt does nothing if you block it using qSleep(). It's like I or thuga wrote in our answers.

Comment: Right, but the window system, which generates the spontaneous events and is not blocked, is going to have the extra clicks lined up for Qt to process after it gets done with the chain of calls for the first click, and the enclosed qSleep(). And since the spontaneous event queue would still be not empty, Qt would not leave the spontaneous event loop. Thus, seemingly, all those extra clicks should be blocked since the queued call to unblock only occurs in the posted event loop, which is after the spontaneous event loop.

Comment: Of course, my expectation of what should go on is off. I'm curious to know what exactly is going on. I'm going to try to debug and research further.

Comment: I see your point. That's indeed strange behavior. I'll also try to dig bit more.

Comment: Added why at the top.

Comment: It would be so easy by just blocking the signal before calling the slot

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens as far as I can tell:

1. You click the button
2. the slots gets called
3. you block the signals of the button
4. you block the event loop with `QTest::qSleep`
5. you click again (this is not processed yet as you blocked the event
   loop)
6. `QTest::qSleep` exits
7. you invoke a queued call to unblock the button signals
8. application goes back to the event loop
9. processes your queued call to `MainWindow::unblock()`
10. then it processes the extra click you made earlier while the event
     loop was blocked

However, if you clicked multiple times while the event loop was blocked, it will process those events before calling `MainWindow::unblock()` for the second time. That is why even if you click the button 4 consecutive times, your slot gets called only twice.

Comment: My understanding of the event loop is that the spontaneous event sub-loop will continue looping until the spontaneous event queue is empty. If this is true, then step 9 (processing the queued call to `MainWindow::unblock()`) would actually swap places with step 10 (processing the extra click) since the extra click would be added to the spontaneous event queue and thus be processed before the posted event loop, where the queued call would occur.

Comment: I'm going off of the conceptual representation of the event loop at this link: [https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq11-events.html](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq11-events.html).

Comment: @RedKrovvy Well if you look at the link you posted, it states: *First, the event loop processes any posted events until the queue is empty. Then, it processes the spontaneous events until there are none left*. Posted events are processed first, which means the queued slot call, and then the spontaneous events are processed, which means the click that happened while the event loop was blocked.

Comment: Yes, I'm totally going off of the logic of that article. That first click is processed, even blocked by the sleep; all within the spontaneous event loop. Because of the sleep, there is time for the extra clicks to accumulate in the window system, which means that when the chain of calls returns for the first click, the spontaneous event loop would not end, given that there are those extra clicks in the window system queue. Thus, all those extra clicks should lead to blocked signals, as the queued unblock call would only happen after the spontaneous loop ends and the posted event loop begins.

Comment: Of course, my understanding of things is off. I'd like to resolve what the article says about the Qt event system and what the test program's results are. Clearly, there's something more to the Qt event loop than the article indicates.

Comment: @RedKrovvy Well I dug through the source code, and for windows Qt uses [`PeekMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.85).aspx) to get events from the queue. And it states the following: `If no filter is specified, messages are processed in the following order:
Sent messages,
Posted messages,
Input (hardware) messages and system internal events,
Sent messages (again),
WM_PAINT messages,
WM_TIMER messages`. And slots go to the `Posted messages` category, while mouse events go into `Input...` category.

Comment: What you're saying opposes what the article [https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq11-events.html](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq11-events.html) is saying about the Qt event loop. It says there are three sub-loops: 1) posted event loop, 2) spontaneous event loop, and 3) posted event loop. If Qt used the above looping of messages, the sub-loop pattern would be 1) posted event loop and 2) spontaneous/input event loop. Maybe the article is off; I'm going to dig some more.

Comment: Aaron's answer cleared things up for me. It seems there can still be pending window system input events that are not processed before moving on to the posted event loop.

Comment: @RedKrovvy You take it too literally what the article says. That is just a conceptualized snippet, not the actual source code. If you look at the event loop [source code for unix](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qeventdispatcher_unix.cpp.html#_ZN20QEventDispatcherUNIX13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE), you will notice there is only ONE loop, not three. Even for [windows](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qeventdispatcher_win.cpp.html#509) there are only two loops.

Comment: Yeah, I was noticing the same for the windows code when I was checking it out. Oh well. And thanks for contributing to the answer, thuga.